# How to create and call function with same name as other function?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces

I am working on my own library and I want to create function max(). I know that function like this exists in C++ and it isn't in namespace std, so erasing using namespace std; won't help. I am creating this function in my namespace like this:

```
namespace ml
{
    template<typename T>T max(T cntr, int size)//I'm getting errors here
    {
         sort(cntr,0,size-1);//my function which just sorts elements, it's working fine
         return cntr[size-1];
    }
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "mylib.hpp"

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int* arr, n;
    std::cin>>n;
    arr = new int [n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         arr[i] = rand()%100;
    }
    int maximum = ml::max(arr,n);//I'm getting errors here
    std::cout<<maximum<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for grammatical mistakes if i've done so.

Comment: It would help if you included the error message. From the looks of it, your template parameter T is deduced as an int array but you are passing back an int, which is obviously not the same. The issue has nothing to do with namespaces or function names.

Comment: There is one problem, i am from Poland and i'm using polish version of Visual Studio so i don't know what are english translations, all i can do is copy past them to Google translate or post only error codes

Comment: T is deduces as an int* but you are return8ng an int.

Comment: The standard-library function `max` **is** defined in `std`.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the function is to search a C-style array, the signature should be `template <typename T> T max(T* cntr, int size)`. (note the `T*` as the type of `cntr`) That way, when it's called with an `int*`, `T` is deduced as `int`, and that's the correct return type.